# What is difference in UniswapV2 router address and pair address? and when they occur?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, uniswap, evm

I am currently working on a pre-built ERC20 contract code that uses two different addresses from UniswapV2 to do validations in its logic.

```
uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);

uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());
```

Inside the `_transfer` function it checks if `from` or `to` parameters equal to `address(uniswapV2Router)` or `uniswapV2Pair`.

I am trying to understand why and when to use each of those addresses especially `uniswapV2Pair` and when my `transfer` function is called with any of those addresses as input parameters.

Comment: Router provides the high level API for swapping, the pair contract implements the swapping logic.